# Completion queue configuration

Tags: grpc

Using an async service with a completion queue, is it possible to configure the size of the cq ?
If not, are their any rules applied on the completion queue lifecycle ?

I'm using grpc 1.13.1 and when I looked into the implementation , I didn't find anything like it ( in the server settings nor in the completion queue attributes).

Althought the pending_tags configuration for the GRPC_TRACE variable doesnt work properly on my version ( I get this message : Unknown trace var :'pending_tags' ) , I was able to display the size of the queue enabling 'all' traces.

The question was asked on this thread : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/LTxgMYBx0yk of google groups. Has anything changed since then?

Thnak you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CompletionQueue API does not expose the 'size' or the number of pending tags on the completion queue. As for pending_tags trace, I believe it is a Debug Only flag, and would only work if gRPC is compiled in Debug mode.